# Xamarin.Forms.Labs Mediapicker not working on iOS 8

Tags: xamarin

Apparently Mediapicker functionality was changed in iOS 8, resulting in Xamarin.Forms.Lab's mediapicker solution failing. Does anyone know of a workaround for this or, lacking that, and alternate multiplatform solution for accessing the camera and media library for Android and iOS in Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

Error on my part. This is working just fine - the problem was that calling mediapicker functionality from DisplayActionSheet was causing problems.